# Chai assert.deepEqual throws error "TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object" when using atob

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, jsdom

I'm using Chai and Mocha to run tests on my helper functions. I used JSDOM to include atob and btoa. This is my setup.js file:

```js
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

const jsdom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
const { window } = jsdom;

global.window = window;
global.document = window.document
global.btoa = window.btoa;
global.atob = window.atob;
```

When I try to run my tests, I get this error:

`TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object.`

My test function:

```js
describe('helpers', () => {
  const testObject = { id: 1 };
  const encodedObject = base64EncodeObject(testObject);
  const decodedObject = base64DecodeObject(encodedObject);
  
  describe('base64DecodeObject()', () => {
    it('decoded object should match original object', () => {
      assert.deepEqual(decodedObject, testObject);
    });
  });
});
```

Target function:

```js
const base64DecodeObject = (base64String) => {
  let object = atob(base64String);
  object = JSON.parse(object);
  return object;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that you're only going only part-way towards mimicking a DOM environment in Node. You set a few variables and stop there, and so you end up with something which is neither a stock Node environment, nor a DOM environment.

`chai` uses `deep-eql` to perform deep comparison, and `deep-eql` uses a package named `type-detect` to do some of its work. `type-detect` performs a test that indicates to it that it is running in a DOM environment and eventually it tries to do [this](https://github.com/chaijs/type-detect/blob/8ec24272d6733fae7954fc09660c72d52ce317a9/index.js#L173):

```
if (obj instanceof globalObject.HTMLElement && obj.tagName === 'BLOCKQUOTE') {
```

Since you did not copy `HTMLElement` from `window` to `global`, then it fails with the error you get. You can fix it by adding:

```
global.HTMLElement = window.HTMLElement;
```